# How to browse text file and show the data in text area in HTA

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

The case is that I have one browse button and text area is it possible when load text file, to show all data in that text area.

Final View:

```
--------------
|C:\1.txt    |  BROWSE
--------------

-----------------------------------------------
|  Some example                               |
|               Data                          | 
|                     from                    |
|                              1.txt          |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably having a code like this:

```
iStream = fso.OpenTextFile('some_text_file.txt', 1, true);
text = iStream.ReadAll();
iStream.Close();
```

If `text` contains tabs, you can't show them in the `textarea` element. However, using `pre` will show the text as it is:

```
document.getElementById('text').innerText = text;
```

And in `HTML` there should be:

```
<pre id="text"></pre>
```

Comment: Great example Teemu. I did with little different way, thanks for the directions.